# Is IISExpress Single-Threaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, claims-based-identity, httpcontext

I am in the process of writing a custom .Net app that utilizes Claims for security, since we're crossing many boundaries - web, API, batch processing and so on. During development, there are occasions where I'll create something in the system while logged in via Chrome and then I'll go to test the newly created item via a different account in Edge and somehow `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` corresponds to my Chrome session. I do set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` behind the scenes, but my understanding has always been that all requests into IIS spawn a new thread, so I can't figure out why the Edge requests are being processed as if they are the Chrome requests.

Is it possible that it's sharing this information because Visual Studio is in debug mode?

Comment: _"...requests into IIS spawn a new thread..."_ - most likely the request will come in on the next available thread pool thread.  So thread IDs over time won't be unique

Comment: @rubyhaus actually wwhat is your concern , i'm assuming when there are request for same user in chrome , you don't want to allow him in other browsers , is this you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIS (and thus IISExpress, which is IIS packaged in an "application" format) is multi-threaded.  However, you have made some incorrect assumptions.

First, no.  A new request does NOT spawn a new thread, it runs on a thread pool thread, and these thread pools are re-used after the previous request finishes (or, as you'll see in a minute, when an async request waits).

Second, you should NOT set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, because not only is IIS multi-threaded, it's asynchronous.   This means that if your thread waits, when it resumes it might be running on a different thread than the thread it started on.

Third, `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is typically the identity of the worker process (or AppPool) identity, changing this changes the security context the entire thread runs under.  A much better option is to use the `WindowsImpersonationContext` class to do impersonation (which is what I assume you're trying to do).

```
WindowsIdentity clientId = (WindowsIdentity)User.Identity;

// When 'using' block ends, the thread reverts back to previous Windows identity,
// because under the hood WindowsImpersonationContext.Undo() is called by Dispose()
using (WindowsImpersonationContext wic = clientId.Impersonate())
{
    // do your work that needs the identity
}
```

If you do need to set a custom principal you should usually be using `HttpContext.Current.User` rather than Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

Comment: I do set `HttpContext.Current.User` in the web side, but without referencing `System.Web` everywhere, how do I let the underlying libraries (mainly a business layer) know who the authenticated user is? I'm trying to avoid referencing System.Web, because not everything will use web components. I have long been under the impression that the Membership API's from Microsoft set the ThreadPrincipal, hence going that route.

Comment: @RubyHaus - Yes, Microsoft's code often does many things that we, ourselves generally shouldn't, because MS knows what it's doing and properly handles the cleanup and edge cases, we often don't know enough about the internals, and it's usually best to avoid them.  Are you doing some kind of custom authentication?  Can you simply pass the Principal to the library from the web layer?

Comment: I was hoping there was a more seemless way to go about it, but I can probably come up with a way to do it. Thanks for the help!