# IIS and C# thread lock

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have doubts regarding threads and IIS with C#, 
I would appreciate someone's help.

I'm not a very skilled C# programmer so please be nice, I will
describe the problem, then I will show my piece of code,
and finally I will ask two questions.

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**

I have a web api method that needs to access to the same folder on
disk on each request, but each call should not access to the folder
if there is already another thread accessing the mentioned folder,
in other words, only one request at a time can access the folder.

**CODE SNIPPET ORIGINAL VERSION (using Monitors)**

I give an example of my problem using the entity class "banana" (:P)
each request contains an id of a banana and this id is used to
verify if there is another request that is already accessing the
folder.

```
using System.Web.Hosting;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

[RoutePrefix("api/banana")]
public class BananaController
{
    private static readonly object bananasLocksAccess = new object();
    private static readonly Dictionary<long, object> bananasLocks = new Dictionary<long, object>();

    [Route("AccessBananaFolder")]
    [TokenAuthorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public BananaResponse AccessFolderWithBananaId(long bananaId)
    {
        BananaResponse r = new BananaResponse();
        Boolean bananaLockTaken = false;
        object bananaLocker = LockBanana(bananaId);
        try
        {
             System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(bananaLocker, ref bananaLockTaken);
             if (bananaLockTaken)
             {
                // safe code to access the folder of bananas
                // ...
                r = new BananaResponse("OK ACCESSING THE FOLDER");
             }
             else
             {
                r = new BananaResponse("COULD NOT ACCESS THE FOLDER RIGTH NOW, TRY AGAIN LATER");
             }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            r = new BananaResponse("AN ERROR OCURRED ACCESSING THE FOLDER OF BANANAS");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (bananaLockTaken)
            {
                System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(bananaLocker);
            }
        }

        return r;
    }


    private static object LockBanana(long bananaId)
    {
        object bananaLocker;
        lock (bananasLocksAccess) {
            if (bananasLocks.ContainsKey(bananaId))
            {
                bananaLocker = bananasLocks[bananaId];
            }
            else
            {
                bananaLocker = new object();
                bananasLocks[bananaId] = bananaLocker;
            }
        }
        return bananaLocker;
    }
}
```

**My questions are**

- 1) Is this a correct aproach to solve the problem in C#?
- 2) Since IIS manage the requests/calls with a pool of threads
  ([Is IISExpress Single-Threaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43382775/is-iisexpress-single-threaded)), is there any change that two different request access the folder
  beacause are managed by the same thread in the pool?

Thank you very much in advance!

===========================================================

Update!

**CODE SNIPPET VERSION 2 (using Mutex)**

OK as ***@STW*** suggested in his reply, I did a new version
of the code but this time I use a Mutex to restrict 
the access to a Set, this set contains all the ids
of bananas that are currently accessing the folder of
bananas (remember that is one temp folder for 
each banana id), this new version also improves the
cleanup issue mentiond by ***@Remus Rusanu*** on the reply of
the main question.

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/banana")]
public class BananaController
{
    private static readonly Mutex bananasLocksAccess = new Mutex(false, "29c447fe-d146-4ea7-ac16-bb8e453ee065");
    private static readonly HashSet<long> bananasLocks = new HashSet<long>();

    [Route("AccessBananaFolder")]
    [TokenAuthorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public BananaResponse AccessFolderWithBananaId(long bananaId)
    {
        BananaResponse r = new BananaResponse();
        bool bananaLockTaken = false;
        try
        {
             bananaLockTaken = LockBanana(bananaId);
             if (bananaLockTaken)
             {
                // safe code to access the folder of bananas
                // ...
                r = new BananaResponse("OK ACCESSING THE FOLDER");
             }
             else
             {
                r = new BananaResponse("COULD NOT ACCESS THE FOLDER RIGTH NOW, TRY AGAIN LATER");
             }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            r = new BananaResponse("AN ERROR OCURRED ACCESSING THE FOLDER OF BANANAS");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (bananaLockTaken)
            {
                UnlockBanana(bananaId);
            }
        }

        return r;
    }


    private static bool LockBanana(long bananaId)
    {
        bool lockTaken = false;
        try
        {
            lockTaken = bananasLocksAccess.WaitOne(0);
            if (lockTaken)
            {
                lockTaken = !bananasLocks.Contains(bananaId);
                if (lockTaken)
                {
                    bananasLocks.Add(bananaId);
                    lockTaken = true;
                }
            }
            bananasLocksAccess.ReleaseMutex();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // could not complete the lock,  the user should try again later
        }
        return lockTaken;
    }

    private static void UnlockBanana(long bananaId)
    {
        try
        {
            bool lockTaken = bananasLocksAccess.WaitOne();
            if (lockTaken)
            {
                bananasLocks.Remove(bananaId);
            }
            bananasLocksAccess.ReleaseMutex();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // the lock was released already
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186384/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-sullivan-iis-and-c-thread-lock).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code is executing in IIS there is the possibility of there being multiple instances of your code running across multiple processes. 
 Synchronizing across processes requires an Operating-System level lock, and the [System.Threading.Mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=netframework-4.7.2) class is specifically designed for that.

`Mutex` has two modes–**local** and **named**.  To work cross-process you'll want to use the named mode, for a name I'd recommend hard-coding a randomly generated GUID.

Comment: I did an update of my original question, at the end of it I added a version of the code using Mutex, can you please give me a feedback of that version? I don't understand the why I need a random GUID, maybe with a hardcoded string is enough, what you think?

Comment: A hardcoded string is all you need, a random GUID (copied and pasted as a hard-coded string) is a common approach

Comment: OK thanks!, I edited the code again to put that GUID